# Access in page an object from MasterPage that inherits from another MasterPage

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I have the following hierarchy:

```
Site.Master
    Site2.Master
        Page1.aspx
        Page2.aspx
    Page3.aspx
    Page4.aspx
```

On Page3 and Page4 I can access an object on Site.Master using <%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Site.Master" %> on aspx file.

**How can I access same object on Page1 and Page2?**

I tried:

1) Put <%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Site.Master" %> on Page1.aspx but I receive an error.

2) Put <%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Site.Master" %> on Site2.Master and <%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Site2.Master" %> on Page1.aspx. Page1.aspx open but I can't access object using Master property.

**Thank you.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public Site TopMasterPage
{
    get
    {
        return (this.Master as Site) ?? this.Master.Master as Site;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. To others, I added this code on my Page1.aspx.cs and Page2.aspx.cs after "public partial class Page1 : System.Web.UI.Page {" and use TopMasterPage.ObjectName to access objects.